# Unusual shape behaviour in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I've been trying to code a 2 layer NN in numpy. While on it, I found this strange behaviour in how the matrix w0 changes its shape as it enters the loop. The shape for `w0` is `(3,1)` and for `X` it is `(4,3)`. The result must be `(4,1)` but instead as the program enters the loop, `w0` becomes `(4,4)`. Outside the loop, it works just fine. Also, this happens when I use `np.dot(X,w0)` but works just fine when I use `np.dot(w0.T,X.T)`. Here's the code:

```
def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv == True:
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    X = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [1,1,1]])

    y = np.array([0,0,1,1]).T

    w0 = np.random.normal(0,0.1,(3,1))
    w0.shape


    for iter in range(10000):
      #forward propagation
      #l0 = X
      multiply = np.dot(X,w0)
      if iter == 1: print(multiply.shape)


      l1 = sigmoid(multiply)
      if iter == 1:
          print(w0)
          print(multiply.shape)
          print(X.shape)
          print(w0.shape)
          print(l1.shape)

      #Calculating error:
      error = y-l1
      if iter == 1: print(error.shape)

      #Backpropagating for update
      d_l1 = error*sigmoid(l1, True)
      if iter == 1: print(d_l1.shape)

      #Update weights : Shape -- (4*3).T * (4*1) = (3*1)
      w0 = w0 + np.dot(np.transpose(X), d_l1.T) 

print ('Results after training:')
print (l1)
```

Comment: Because you are adding a 2d matrix to `w0` at the end of the for loop as `np.dot(np.transpose(X), d_l1.T)` which changes the dimensions from `(3, 1)` to `(3, 4)`

Comment: `y = np.array([0,0,1,1]).T` - were you expecting that to produce a column vector or something? `y` is one-dimensional. `T` does nothing to a one-dimensional array.